# How many times has a 4 game sweep occurred during the Stanley Cup finals?

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, nhl, postseason, stanley-cup

After their win on [June 9, 2014](http://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/201406090NYR.html), the LA Kings are one game away from winning the Stanley Cup. If they win their next game, they will sweep the NY Rangers to win the Stanley Cup.

Since the adoption of the seven-game series in 1939, how many times has a 4 game sweep occurred during the Stanley Cup finals? Please list the team and the year of accomplishment.

Comment: For reference, the following years also contained sweeps during the Stanley Cup finals, but these finals were not won in 4 games: [1935](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1935.html), [1932](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1932.html), [1930](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1930.html), [1929](http://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/NHL_1929.html)

Comment: In addition to @MASTERMIND_ED's comment, the best of 7 series were adopted by NHL starting 38-39.

Comment: [List of Stanley Cup Champions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Stanley_Cup_champions#NHL_champions_.28since_1927.29) on Wikipedia has also result of the series in the final.

Comment: Related, or maybe "anti-duplicate": https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/26049/3671

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been 20 Stanley Cup finals sweeps. The list below is also available in [this answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/4921), at [TSN](http://web.archive.org/web/20130503105854/http://www.tsn.ca/nhl/feature/?id=5844), or any respected source that tracks NHL statistics.

| Year | Winning Team | Losing Team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1998 | Detroit Red Wings | Washington Capitals |
| 1997 | Detroit Red Wings | Philadelphia Flyers |
| 1996 | Colorado Avalanche | Florida Panthers |
| 1995 | New Jersey Devils | Detroit Red Wings |
| 1992 | Pittsburgh Penguins | Chicago Blackhawks |
| 1988 | Edmonton Oilers | Boston Bruins |
| 1983 | New York Islanders | Edmonton Oilers |
| 1982 | New York Islanders | Vancouver Canucks |
| 1977 | Montreal Canadiens | Boston Bruins |
| 1976 | Montreal Canadiens | Philadelphia Flyers |
| 1970 | Boston Bruins | St. Louis Blues |
| 1969 | Montreal Canadiens | St. Louis Blues |
| 1968 | Montreal Canadiens | St. Louis Blues |
| 1960 | Montreal Canadiens | Toronto Maple Leafs |
| 1952 | Detroit Red Wings | Montreal Canadiens |
| 1949 | Toronto Maple Leafs | Detroit Red Wings |
| 1948 | Toronto Maple Leafs | Detroit Red Wings |
| 1944 | Montreal Canadiens | Chicago Black Hawks |
| 1943 | Detroit Red Wings | Boston Bruins |
| 1941 | Boston Bruins | Detroit Red Wings |

Answer (score 2):

Here ya go!

```
Year       Winning Team       Losing Team
1998    Detroit Red Wings   Washington Capitals
1997    Detroit Red Wings   Philadelphia Flyers
1996    Colorado Avalanche  Florida Panthers
1995    New Jersey Devils   Detroit Red Wings
1992    Pittsburgh Penguins Chicago Blackhawks
1988    Edmonton Oilers     Boston Bruins
1983    New York Islanders  Edmonton Oilers
1982    New York Islanders  Vancouver Canucks
1977    Montreal Canadiens  Boston Bruins
1976    Montreal Canadiens  Philadelphia Flyers
1970    Boston Bruins           St. Louis Blues
1969    Montreal Canadiens  St. Louis Blues
1968    Montreal Canadiens  St. Louis Blues
1960    Montreal Canadiens  Toronto Maple Leafs
1952    Detroit Red Wings   Montreal Canadiens
1949    Toronto Maple Leafs Detroit Red Wings
1948    Toronto Maple Leafs Detroit Red Wings
1944    Montreal Canadiens  Chicago Black Hawks
1943    Detroit Red Wings   Boston Bruins
1941    Boston Bruins       Detroit Red Wings
```

Comment: Can you add a source?

Comment: I like your answer, but please also include to source.