# History of reverse sweeps in the Stanley cups finals?

Tags: ice-hockey, nhl, postseason, stanley-cup

I tought the habs being 0-3 in the stanley cups finals would make every sport news site in Montreal dig up every time a stanley cup reverse sweep happened to show there is still hope; but nobody seem to have done so.

So, historically speaking, what teams did complete a reverse sweep (wining 4 in a row when down 0-3 in a series)?

Comment: Related, or maybe an "anti-duplicate": https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/4919/3671

Comment: Its close, but the question requests Sweep (where a team wins 4-0) and I'm asking for reverse sweeps (where the winning team comes back from 0-3 to win 4-3)

Comment: yes they're related, maybe reverse related? lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [list of comebacks from 0-3 down in NHL playoffs (entirely, not just the Stanley Cup finals) is very short](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_teams_to_overcome_3%E2%80%930_series_deficits#Successful_comebacks):

- 1942 Stanley Cup Finals (Leafs over Red Wings)
- 1975 quarterfinals (Islanders over Penguins)
- 2010 conference semifinals (Flyers over Bruins)
- 2014 first round (Kings over Sharks)

Answer (score 3):

The [1942 Toronto Maple Leafs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1942_Stanley_Cup_Finals) are the only team in the NHL history to make a comeback after being down 3-0 in the Stanley Cup Finals series. All other reverse sweeps were made in the first 3 rounds.